# Passing IEnumerable<int> to a WebApi action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this controller action:

```
[ActionName("GetMany")] [HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetMany([FromUri] IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

I'm also using a custom model binder as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052378/webapi-routing-with-integer-array-and-actions). My question is different from this linked question because, even though I followed the answers suggested there, it is still not working when using a custom `ModelBinder` as it's throwing an exception mentioned below.

I've got this routing configured:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByAction",
    routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" },
    constraints: null
);
```

And on the client side, I do:

```
public IEnumerable<MyEntity> LoadMany(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var url = "Api/MyEntity/GetMany?ids={0}";
    var s = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format(url, string.Join(",", ids)));

    response = client.GetAsync(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s)).Result;

    return null; //for now 
}
```

However, response is throwing a Not Found exception.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I removed the registering of the custom model binder, and I changed the action to:

```
[ActionName("GetMany")] [HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetMany([ModelBinder(typeof(ArrayModelBinder))] IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

And now I get the following exception:

> HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)

So if `?` is not allowed in the Url, and without removing validation, how is it possible to pass the array to the action? Would changing the `Get` to a `Post` make sense (in order to use request.body)?

Comment: Instead of `"Api/MyEntity/GetMany?ids={0}"` have you tried full url? (`"http:/www.example.com/Api/MyEntity/GetMany?ids={0}"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the controller action as

```
public IHttpActionResult GetMany([FromUri] int[] ids)
```

and pass the URL as:

```
?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3...
```

It should just work without a custom binder

Comment: I would prefer passing the URL as ?ids=1,2,3